# Como validar um campo de telefone com Angular?

Tags: html, angular, input

Olá! Estou criando uma aplicação em Angular 10. Nela, tenho um formulário de cadastro em que o usuário insere o telefone em um input. Preciso limitar o valor inserido no campo de DDD e no campo de telefone, de forma que ele não consiga submeter se não tiver um valor mínimo no campo e também apareça uma mensagem de erro. Já tentei usar min e max direto no html mas não funcionou. Estou tentando criar uma diretiva mas penso que deve ter alguma forma melhor de fazer isso. Como posso proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a lib [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

```
<input mask="(00) 0000-00009" id="telefone" placeholder="telefone">
```

Lembre-se de ler a documentação e importar o modulo corretamente.

Ele vai gerar um erro caso esteja mal formatado, mas você pode utilizar o min="14" e o max="15" e validar se está abaixo do 14, o telefone está incorreto.

Comment: pode usar ```<input mask="(00) 0000-0000||(00) 0 0000-0000" />``` pra deixar o campo flexível

Comment: @placementw O 9 deixa dinâmico porque não é obrigatório, ou seja, 3333-3333 e 9999-99999 funcionariam. Testei a sugestão que você sugeriu, mas não funcionou.

Comment: tentou separar os pipes do resto do texto? mandei eles colados na string, agora que vi, aqui sempre usei assim